# efficient file update with flock and move

Tags: php, concurrency, rename, flock

I want to update a file while other processes may be using reading it. PHP `flock()` function allows exactly to do that.

However as I see the flock only takes a file handle .. that generally comes from fopen. If I want to do this efficiently, I don't want to keep the file open and write it, because file is coming over the network and the write operation may span to a few seconds (say 2-3 seconds).

So I was hoping if could write the data to temp file and then move it. In that case readers of the file will only be disturbed when I am renaming it.

Now writing data to temp will not require me to use flock. However how can I move tempfile to actual file correctly using locking.

I also wonder if I would actually need locking in the first place .. wouldn't the move operation will be very quick? Would it hurt simultaineous file reads. And I expect there will be 100s of reads but just one update, and that update will happen once every hour

Answer (score 3):

Rename is atomic in POSIX systems, so you don't need flock. Readers that have already opened the file will be undisturbed. (Justification: An open file handle points to the inode, not to the directory entry. Rename changes just the directory entry.)

However, readers must close and reopen the file to get the new content. If readers keep the file open, they will be able to reread the old content.